# Yakketey Yak problem

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, update-manager, 16.10

I am having a problem with Yakketey Yak. I am an Ubuntu user long time ago, but this 16.10 version is new to me. Can you help me?

```
Image 1 translation - repository informations download failed
 Image 2 translation - 

E: Obtaining failed cdrom://Ubuntu 16.10 _Yakkety Yak_ - Release amd64 (20161012.2)/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  Por favor utilize o apt-cdrom so APT recognizes this CD. apt-get update can't be used to add new cds
E: Obtaining failed http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Obtaining failed http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files download failed. They're ignored or the last ones replaced them.
```

Comment: Sorry, Images don't load..
The first was software manager error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this from a console, it's pretty simple. All you need to do is drop into a root shell and disable the offending sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:pipelight/stable
```

Finally, disable the CD-ROM source:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find the line that begins with `deb:cdrom` (should be at the top) and place a `#` at the very beginning of the line.

Once you're done, reload the Apt cache:

```
sudo apt update
```

---

This problem happened because Ubuntu was looking for non-existent software sources, was unable to find them, and therefore was unable to learn where some packages are (or aren't in this case). This almost always happens after installs.

Answer (score 2):

Open "System Settings" → "Software & Updates".

In the "Ubuntu Software" tab, uncheck the CDROM checkbox at the bottom.

In the "Other Software" tab, uncheck the two failing PPAs ("pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable" and "pipelight/stable").

Close the window and let it reload the software sources when it asks you for permission to do that afterwards.

Comment: Check. I'm trying to install pipelight plugin but I get same error
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some Index files donwload failed. Were ignored or the old ones replaced them.

Comment: Please post a new question about your follow-up issue (maybe adding a link to this question), as I can't help you at the very moment.